# How to do nested for loops process

Tags: c

I am teaching myself C using Kochan's Programming in C 4th edition. I am stuck on exercise chapter 6 exercise 5, which is where one is supposed to predict the outcome of the following code. Obviously to see the answer one should run the code. My problem is that I am not understanding how the program is reaching the output.

Here is the code in questions

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  numbers[10] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int  i, j;

    for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
        for (i = 0;  i < j;  ++i)
            numbers[j]  +=  numbers[i];

    for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
        printf("%i ", numbers[j]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My answer to this questions was completely wrong, so I sat down with pen and paper and manually tried to run the program.

The actual output

```
1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256
```

I didn't manually do all ten, because I knew I was wrong, but below I explained my logic in executing the program.

1st run through the loop.

```
j = 0.  i = 0.  numbers[0] = 1           \\initialized when the array was declared

numbers[0] = numbers[0]+numbers[0] (2);

numbers[0] = 2  \\it had previously equaled 1.  

j = j + 1
```

It is still 0 at this point, because the expression i < j was not satisfied when it was evaluated.

Next iteration

```
j = 1, I = 0.

numbers[1] = numbers[1] (0) + number[0] (2)

numbers[1] = 2.
```

Again, it is wrong.

Comment: **Hint:** Each number in the output is twice the one before it.  The first `1` seeds the sequence with a starting number.

Comment: **Point:** `int numbers[10] = { 1 };` provides identical initialization of `numbers`. [§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p19)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19) "all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: `numbers[0] = numbers[0]+numbers[0]` never occurs. When `j=0` and `i=0` the 2nd loop conditional `i < j` is false to begin with because `i == j`, not `i < j`.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see what it is doing. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key:

```
for (j = 0;  j < 10;  ++j)
        for (i = 0;  i < j;  ++i)
            numbers[j]  +=  numbers[i];
```

This means each number is the sum of all numbers before it, except for the first one, which was `1` to begin with and isn't changed. And that's all!

Comment: I see, the code didn't modify number[0] = 1 because the iteration of the second for loop was not satisfied and so did not execute the program statement following.  Other than that, a typical case of not following the code thoroughly enough to the logical conclusion.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When faced with a problem where you are scratching your head trying to determine what is going on, a few carefully placed `printf` statements assists with (not replaces) the pencil and paper analysis. For example, in your case it isn't immediately clear that for the first iteration of the `j` loop, the `i` loop does not execute. But placing a `printf` above and below the addition within the `i` loop discloses that fact immediately, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[10] = { 1 }, i, j;

    printf ("\n j  i   Result after addition in loop"
            "\n---------------------------------------------\n");
    for (j = 0;  j < 10;  j++)
        for (i = 0;  i < j;  i++) {
            numbers[j]  +=  numbers[i];
            printf (" %d  %d   numbers[%d]: %3d,    numbers[%d]: %d\n",
                    j, i, j, numbers[j], i, numbers[i]);
        }
    putchar ('\n');

    for (j = 0;  j < 10;  j++)
        printf("%i ", numbers[j]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Just looking over the code, your eyes scan over `for (i = 0;  i < j;  i++)` validating the correctness of the loop declaration, but subtly skipping the fact that `i == j` on the first iteration and the `i` loop never executes. The `printf` statements make that clear, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/predict_outcome

 j  i   Result after addition in loop
---------------------------------------------
 1  0   numbers[1]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 2  0   numbers[2]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 2  1   numbers[2]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 3  0   numbers[3]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 3  1   numbers[3]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 3  2   numbers[3]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 4  0   numbers[4]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 4  1   numbers[4]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 4  2   numbers[4]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 4  3   numbers[4]:   8,    numbers[3]: 4
 5  0   numbers[5]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 5  1   numbers[5]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 5  2   numbers[5]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 5  3   numbers[5]:   8,    numbers[3]: 4
 5  4   numbers[5]:  16,    numbers[4]: 8
 6  0   numbers[6]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 6  1   numbers[6]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 6  2   numbers[6]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 6  3   numbers[6]:   8,    numbers[3]: 4
 6  4   numbers[6]:  16,    numbers[4]: 8
 6  5   numbers[6]:  32,    numbers[5]: 16
 7  0   numbers[7]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 7  1   numbers[7]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 7  2   numbers[7]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 7  3   numbers[7]:   8,    numbers[3]: 4
 7  4   numbers[7]:  16,    numbers[4]: 8
 7  5   numbers[7]:  32,    numbers[5]: 16
 7  6   numbers[7]:  64,    numbers[6]: 32
 8  0   numbers[8]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 8  1   numbers[8]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 8  2   numbers[8]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 8  3   numbers[8]:   8,    numbers[3]: 4
 8  4   numbers[8]:  16,    numbers[4]: 8
 8  5   numbers[8]:  32,    numbers[5]: 16
 8  6   numbers[8]:  64,    numbers[6]: 32
 8  7   numbers[8]: 128,    numbers[7]: 64
 9  0   numbers[9]:   1,    numbers[0]: 1
 9  1   numbers[9]:   2,    numbers[1]: 1
 9  2   numbers[9]:   4,    numbers[2]: 2
 9  3   numbers[9]:   8,    numbers[3]: 4
 9  4   numbers[9]:  16,    numbers[4]: 8
 9  5   numbers[9]:  32,    numbers[5]: 16
 9  6   numbers[9]:  64,    numbers[6]: 32
 9  7   numbers[9]: 128,    numbers[7]: 64
 9  8   numbers[9]: 256,    numbers[8]: 128

1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
```

While the pencil and paper alone will disclose what is happening, as you can see by your analysis of:

```
numbers[0] = numbers[0]+numbers[0] (2);

numbers[0] = 2  \\it had previously equaled 1.
```

The old brain isn't foolproof...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing, that the first iteration will do nothing at all because when j=0 and i=0 i is not smaller than j. So numbers[0] stays equal to 1